# Split String and move to newline in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a sample string in which I need to move to a new line if the value is present in the array using Javascript.

```
var str="name:stain empid:145 age:53   Dob:29/07/1993 sex:m"
var arr=['name','age','Dob'];
```

Required output:

```
name:stain empid:145
age:53   
Dob:29/07/1993 sex:m
```

Comment: `str.replace(new RegExp(\`\\b(${arr.join("|")})\\b\`, "g"), "\n$1")`

Comment: thanks @CRice ... it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CRice mention good use of regex.
**$1 is the first group from your regular expression** [MDN RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n)

```js
var str="name:stain empid:145 age:53   Dob:29/07/1993 sex:m"
var arr=['name','age','Dob'];
const result = str.replace(new RegExp(`\\b(${arr.join("|")})\\b`, "g"), "\n$1")
console.log(result)
```